# Jquery setting offset to 0 not working

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a tooltip which pops on a button click only if checkbox is not checked. I am setting the position of the button relative to a label using JQuery. i am hiding the tooltip if the checkbox is checked and then showing it for the same above scenario.

```
    $('#chkbox').change(function(){
        if(($('#chkbox').attr('checked')=="checked") && $('#tooltip').is(':visible')==true){
            $('#tooltip').hide();
        }
});

    $('#Button').click(function(){  
        if(!($('#chkbox').attr('checked')))
        {
            var lbloffset = $('#Label').offset();
            $('#tooltip').offset({top:0,left:0});
            $('#tooltip').offset({top:lbloffset.top-25,left:lbloffset.left+$('#Label').width()});
            $('#tooltip').show();

        }
    });
```

The tooltip hides on checkbox checked but when I again uncheck it and click the button it should show the tooltip at the same position as I am clearing  $('#tooltip').offset({top:0,left:0}); position and again resetting it. But this is not happening, instead the tool tip is adding the new offset position into the old one and shows it somewhere else on the page. I am not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to set the `.offset` once. I'm not clear where you want it to go, but perhaps this is what you want:

```
var lbloffset = $('#Label').offset();
$('#tooltip').offset({top:lbloffset.top-25,left:lbloffset.left+$('#Label').width()});
```

Comment: The offset is getting added every time the button is clicked.

Comment: Is the `#Label` inside the tooltip? Is `$('#Label').offset()` equal to what you expect it to be?

Comment: No the label is not inside tooltip. The offset is getting added every time the button is clicked. like first time if the offset value is ({top:200-25,left:200+20), second time it will be ({top:(200-25)+200-25,left:(200+20)+200+20) and so on.That's why I was trying to reset offset to 0 but it didnt work.

Comment: Without seeing your HTML I can't understand the relationship between `#Label` and `#tooltip`, and can't be much more help to you.

Comment: Guys, I tried 
$('#tooltip').css({'top':lbloffset.top-25,'left':lbloffset.left+$('#Label').width()}); This is working fine. 
I will analyse on offset issue later. Meanwhile if you all find anything, help me with that. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: jQueries `.offset()` is not supposed to set the offset. It's just an abstracted getter method. http://api.jquery.com/offset/
See the *This method does not accept any arguments* part.

Comment: @MildlyInteresting Did I misread [the second part](http://api.jquery.com/offset/#offset2) then?

Comment: Haha I'm sorry. I checked the docs to see if I was right about my assumption and that sentence I quoted seemed pretty much self explaining, so I didn't look any further. Learned something new here, thanks!

Comment: Have the same error actually. I was wondering as well, because sometimes you need to set a new Offset if somebody will resize the page or zoom in.